# Fail showing colors in JavaFX Table

Tags: java, css, windows, javafx

I´ve developed an app in Java-JavaFX. It works perfectly on several comoputers(about 20),, but there is one that dont shows the color of the rows in the table. All computers are wiindows with several versioins. the one which fails is a Winndows 7 64bit.
Here is my code

```
public TableRow<Orden> call(TableView<Orden> tableView) {

    final TableRow<Orden> row = new TableRow<Orden>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Orden orden, boolean empty){
            super.updateItem(orden, empty);

            if(null!=orden) {
                clearPriorityStyle();
                String color = calcularColorRow(orden);
                if(!color.equals("")){
                    this.getStyleClass().add(color);

                }

            }

        }

        private String calcularColorRow(Orden o){
            if(null!=o.getmColorCode()){
                Integer colorCode = o.getmColorCode();
                switch(colorCode){
                case 0:
                    return "";

                case 1:
                    return "rojo";

                case 2:
                    return "verde";

                case 3:
                    return "naranja";

                case 4:
                    return "amarillo";

                case 5:
                    return "azul";
                case 6:
                    return "morado";

                default: 
                    return "";
                }
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }

        private void clearPriorityStyle(){
            ObservableList<String> styleClasses = getStyleClass();
            this.getStyleClass().remove("rojo");
            styleClasses.remove("naranja");
            styleClasses.remove("verde");
            styleClasses.remove("amarillo");
            styleClasses.remove("azul");
            styleClasses.remove("morado");
        }
    };
```

and the .css code:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
.amarillo {
    -fx-control-inner-background: khaki;
-fx-text-fill: blue;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
-fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
}

.errorRow {
    -fx-control-inner-background: green;

-fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
-fx-text-fill: -fx-selection-bar-text;
}
.verde { 
  -fx-control-inner-background: palegreen;
  -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
  -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}

.azul { 
  -fx-control-inner-background: plum;
  -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
  -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}

.naranja { 
  -fx-control-inner-background: coral;
  -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
  -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}
.rojo { 
  -fx-control-inner-background: red;
  -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
  -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}
.morado { 
  -fx-control-inner-background: purple;
  -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
  -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}
.marron { 
  -fx-control-inner-background: brown;
  -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%);
  -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs in your table row factory implementation:

1. `getStyleClass()` returns a list, which can of course contain duplicate items. So you have to ensure that you are not adding the same item twice. The easiest way to do this is to remove all the colors from the style class list each time `updateItem(...)` is called, then just add back the one you need.
2. You are not currently handling the empty case: here you want to make sure you remove any of the style classes you added.

You can fix these in one fell swoop. First note that while `list.remove(item)` removes the *first occurrence* of `item` from a list, `list.removeAll(collection)` will remove *all elements* in the list that belong to the supplied collection. Second, make sure you call `clearPriorityStyle()` even if the table row is empty.

Different versions of JavaFX may implement the table updates differently, so the likely reason you are seeing different behaviors is that one machine is using a version that exposes these bugs, while others are using a version whose implementation just happens to work with your code. Here's a fix:

```
public TableRow<Orden> call(TableView<Orden> tableView) {

    final TableRow<Orden> row = new TableRow<Orden>() {

        final List<String> allStyles = Arrays.asList(
            "", 
            "rojo", 
            "naranja", 
            "verde", 
            "amarillo", 
            "azul", 
            "morado");

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Orden orden, boolean empty){
            super.updateItem(orden, empty);

            clearPriorityStyle();

            if(null!=orden) {
                String color = calcularColorRow(orden);
                if(!color.equals("")){
                    this.getStyleClass().add(color);

                }

            }

        }

        // same as before but a cleaner implementation:
        private String calcularColorRow(Orden o){
            if(null!=o.getmColorCode()){
                int colorCode = o.getmColorCode();
                if (colorCode < allStyles.size()) {
                    return allStyles.get(colorCode);
                }
            } 
            return "" ;
        }   


        private void clearPriorityStyle(){
            ObservableList<String> styleClasses = getStyleClass();
            this.getStyleClass().removeAll(allStyles);
        }

    };

    return row ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think... Your `clearPriorityStyle()` assumes you don't have multiple entries of anything, which you need to prove, but I think that is the case. Surely safer though to make sure you remove everything anyway? These are tricky because you have no control over how `updateItem(...)` is invoked, so you need to make sure it works for *any arbitrary sequence* of invocations of `updateItem(...)`, including with `orden=null` and `empty=true`

Comment: First thanks for the answer! I´m developing in Java 7, and which is Optional class?

Comment: @vLopez `java.util.Optional` was introduced in Java 8. I rolled back to a previous version of the answer that doesn't use it, but why are you using Java 7?

Comment: I made  the program 2 years ago, and it works with a old MSAccess(froom another program) db and in somoe computers with Windows XP. Tomorrow i´ll tell you if the solution works. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Nothing... The colors doesn´t appears on n the computer... Any idea?

Comment: @vLopez  It works fine for me. Either you have things wrong in other code you haven't shown, or it isn't working because you are just using versions of JavaFX that are long out of date.